# PHP: How to change values in an array using if-else statement?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, replace

Suppose I have an array with 10 elements example: array(1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1)

How would I implement a function that replaces the values of an array using an if-else statement to evaluate the elements of the array. Say if the value is one, i would want to have an output of YES and if it is 0, then it is NO. Im sure i would be using a looping statement to evaluate each cells or element. Also, if one element has a value of 1.5 or any floating number, i would also want it to be replaced as YES.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array and check for the element,

```
 if(!$arr[$i]) echo "NO"
 else echo "Yes"
```

You already have the idea, what exactly do you need?